# E-mail sent by workflow cannot be opened

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepint

I have created a workflow with a link to the list filled in on the SP. The e-mail field is a choice list. When the e-mail is sent the receiver cannot open the link as the message is somehow like : the item cannot be opened iT seems it has been deleted or removed. I have changed already the ID columns name to CustomID. I used the Absolute URL in the designer. Any tips? 
Thx Remko

ADDED 17012019
[image]

https://***.sharepoint.com/teams/BUN-Administration/Reporting/Lists/IC%20PayRoll%20Request/132_.000/../DispForm.aspx?ID=132

Comment: Is it possible for you to add screenshot of email action you used in your workflow?

Comment: add a screenshot and the link which is saved into email.

Comment: did you check permissions on the designated sharepoint location?

Comment: Yes, probably the problem is that only the creator has rights to see the item add